# Make a select disabled according to another select

Tags: jquery, select

I want to make some select inputs disabled according to another single select value.

I have 4 selects in a form. The first one (#type_rapport) has 3 choices, and the value of it make the other select inputs shown or hidden. Important note : these selects are filled thanks to PHP.

For example, if you choose V, then #select_v will be shown, while #select_f and #select_g will be hidden.

Here's my form :

```
<form>
<div>
    <select name="type_rapport" id="type_rapport">
        <option>-</option>
        <option value="v" <?php if (isset($_GET[ 'type_rapport']) AND $_GET[ 'type_rapport']=="v" ) echo "selected=\"Selected\ ""; ?>>V</option>
        <option value="f" <?php if (isset($_GET[ 'type_rapport']) AND $_GET[ 'type_rapport']=="f" ) echo "selected=\"Selected\ ""; ?>>F</option>
        <option value="g" <?php if (isset($_GET[ 'type_rapport']) AND $_GET[ 'type_rapport']=="g" ) echo "selected=\"Selected\ ""; ?>>G</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select name="designation" id="select_v" <? if (isset($_GET[ 'type_rapport'])){ if ($_GET[ 'type_rapport']!="v" ) echo "disabled"; } else { echo "disabled"; } ?>>
        <?php $infos=$ bdd->query(...); while ($donnees = $infos->fetch()) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $donnees[0]; ?>" <?php if (isset($_GET[ 'designation']) AND $_GET[ 'designation']==$donnees[0]) echo "selected=\"Selected\ ""; ?>>
            <?php echo $donnees[1]; ?>
        </option>
        <?php } $infos->closeCursor(); ?></select>
</div>
<div>
    <select name="famille" id="select_f" <? if (isset($_GET[ 'type_rapport'])){ if ($_GET[ 'type_rapport']!="f" ) echo "disabled"; } else { echo "disabled"; } ?>>
        <?php $infos=$ bdd->query('...'); while ($donnees = $infos->fetch()) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $donnees[0]; ?>" <?php if(isset($_GET[ 'famille']) AND $_GET[ 'famille']==$donnees[7]) echo "selected=\"Selected\ ""; ?>>
            <?php echo $donnees[8]; ?>
        </option>
        <?php } $infos->closeCursor(); ?></select>
</div>
<div>
    <select name="groupe" id="select_g" <? if (isset($_GET[ 'type_rapport'])){ if ($_GET[ 'type_rapport']!="g" ) echo "disabled"; } else { echo "disabled"; } ?>>
        <?php $infos=$ bdd->query('...'); while ($donnees = $infos->fetch()) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $donnees[0]; ?>" <?php if(isset($_GET[ 'groupe']) AND $_GET[ 'groupe']==$donnees[10]) echo "selected=\"Selected\ ""; ?>>
            <?php echo $donnees[11]; ?>
        </option>
        <?php } $infos->closeCursor(); ?></select>
</div>
```

And my jQuery script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#select_v').closest('div').addClass('method_options').hide();
$('#select_f').closest('div').addClass('method_options').hide();
$('#select_g').closest('div').addClass('method_options').hide();
$('#type_rapport').change(function () {
    $('div.method_options').hide();
    $('#select_' + $(this).val()).closest('div').show();
    $('#select_' + $(this).val()).removeAttribute('disabled');
});
});
```

The first time the user view the form, #select_v, #select_f and #select_g should be disabled until the user choose a option in the #type_rapport select input. I tried to add the removeAttribute line but it didn't work.

When the user submit the form, the same page is called with the GET method as you can see in my php code. The option for #type_rapport is selected, but the associated select is not shown at all (though it's not disabled thanks to my condition).

Here's a jsFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/wrnk/3Yy4H/

Can someone help me for those issues ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't use php code in fiddle, please update the fiddle with your correct requirements.......

Comment: Ok, my bad. Wrote this to show how my options were created.